# JVM Invalid Nested Class Name?

Tags: java, jvm, verifyerror

The compiler for a JVM-based programming language currently that I am working on uses this code to run a specified `main` method after compilation:

```
URL url = DyvilCompiler.config.outputDir.toURI().toURL();
Class c = Class.forName(mainType, false, new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url }, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()));
Method m = c.getMethod("main", String[].class);
m.invoke(null, new Object[] { args });
```

However, when compiling this code:

```
package dyvil.test
// some uninteresting import stuff
public class Main
{   
    @ArrayConvertible
    case class IntVector([int] ints = [ 1, 2 ])
    
    public static void main([String] args)
    {
        println(IntVector())
        println([ 1, 2, 3 ] as IntVector)
    }
}
```

The ClassLoader fails with the inner class (that is actually a nested `static` class):

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "Ldyvil/test/Main$IntVector;" in class file dyvil/test/Main$IntVector
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at dyvil.test.Main.main(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at dyvil.tools.compiler.util.TestThread.run(TestThread.java:32)
```

Note that the class files generated for Main `dyvil/test/Main` and IntVector `dyvil/test/Main$IntVector` do define the inner class relation:

```
Inner classes:
    [inner class info: #2 dyvil/test/Main$IntVector, outer class info: #7 dyvil/test/Main
     inner name: #9 IntVector, accessflags: 8 static]
  Enclosing Method: #7  #0 dyvil/test/Main
```

---

## What is the problem with the `Ldyvil/test/Main$IntVector;` signature?

---

Also, when adding the output directory to the classpath and changing the code to

```
Class c = Class.forName(mainType)
```

everything works well without any errors.

---

***EDIT***: Not only does this cause problems with the JVM, but when using a class like this in Eclipse by `import`ing it, Code Completions stop working completely.

Comment: `case class IntVector([int] ints = [ 1, 2 ])` isn't a valid Java statement, as far as I know. Isn't this Scala code?

Comment: It's a custom programming language and a custom compiler.

Comment: Oh I see I had missed that part when I first read the question, sorry ;)

Comment: Yeah they are quite similar. Also note that although the nested class is not declared `static`, it is still a nested class that doesn't capture the outer one.

Comment: Care to post the full javap output of the inner class?  The VerifyError message is incomplete in that it doesn't tell us what part of the class file contains the supposedly invalid class name.

Comment: At a guess, I think you're using a signature (with 'L' and ';') where just the class name is expected.  It is strange that changing class loaders makes a difference, though.

Comment: Whoops, looks like I found the error. I was indeed using a signature instead of a class name with a `CHECKCAST` instruction. But it is still interesting that using an URLClassLoader instead of the default one causes this error.

Comment: You should add this as answer to your own question.